# FFMPEG converted file for jwplayer shows black

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

im new to ffmpeg, and I'm trying to convert it to mp4 to play on jwplayer, the video converts, the sound is good, but all i can see is black color, maybie anyone knows the answer to this problem?

```
ffmpeg -y -i Bear.wmv -vcodec libx264 -b:v 1000k -bufsize 1000k -preset:v ultrafast -movflags +faststart -crf 0 -vf scale=800:400 -ab 128k -vsync 2 -strict -2 outas.mp4
```

my ffmpeg code
my ffmpeg version 2.0.1

Comment: Do you have a link to the media file and/or your player embed?

Comment: Please include the complete ffmpeg console output.